# Showing the build command Xcode uses

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode5

Is there a way to see the xcodebuild command that Xode uses for building? 
I have created a library file with Xcodebuild command from Terminal. But there are some differences between the files generated from terminal and Xcode UI.

Answer (score 0):

I use this behavior to switch to the log when building starts.

[image: Building Start Behavior].

In the log you can find all the commands Xcode is executing.